# Un verbe pour mesurer le volume ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, terminologie, demande-de-mot

Existe-t-il un verbe en français qui permet d'exprimer quel est le volume d'un objet, comme il en existe pour le poids ou la longueur ?

Pour le poids : un cube **pèse** 1kgp.

Pour la longueur : un cube **mesure** 50cm.

Pour le volume : un cube **???** 1L.

Je reconnais qu'on pourrait dire qu'un cube *contient* 1L, mais ce n'est pas tout à fait la même idée : on mesure le volume de ce qui est dans le cube et pas le volume du cube lui-même.  Par exemple, si une bouteille contient 50cl d'eau, ça ne veut pas dire que la bouteille a un volume de 50 cl. Et on ne dit pas "l'eau contient 50 cl" comme on pourrait dire "l'eau pèse 50g".

Comment: Techniquement il ne faudrait pas dire qu'un objet "pèse" un certain poid, même si c'est rentré dans le language courant. Il faudrait dire "un cube a une masse de 1kg"

Comment: @BaptisteGavaldan Il manque alors aussi une acception étendue du verbe *masser* : **un cube *masse* 1 kg** ;-)

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda : Je connais bien sûr P=m.g mais néanmoins... je ne vois pas la moindre incongruité à ***peser un poids*** (qui se trouve ainsi et tout aussi légitimement *pesant*. Après, qu'il ne faille pas exprimer le résultat en grammes... c'est une autre histoire.

Comment: @jlliagre : Oui! Tout à fait! on pourrait aussi proposer *personnifier* (En hommage à Roberval), *trébucher* (en hommage à l'autre) mais bon après aussi... on s'en *balance* un peu... ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt I'm probably just showing my ignorance about the difference between mass and force, but why did your edit require changing "kg" to "kgp"?

Comment: @PapaPoule : Pour parler de kilogramme-**p**oids qui, en toute exactitude correspond à l'unité de poids, laissant le kilogramme (tout-court) aux masses. Aucune honte à ne pas le savoir... c'est juste pour chipoter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On peut utiliser le verbe *occuper*.

> Cet objet occupe 3 mètres cubes.
>
> Cet objet occupe un volume de 3 mètres cube.

Avec la mesure du litre, c'est peut-être un peu inhabituel. On peut alors préciser qu'on parle dun volume comme suit

> Cet objet occupe un volume de 3 litres.

Dans la vie courante, on peut utiliser, comme pour d'autres mesures, le verbe *faire*, qui est certes peu précis et "passe-partout":

> Cet objet fait 3 mètres cube.

Answer (score 11):

Il existe effectivement un verbe fait tout exprès pour cela :

[***Cuber***](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cuber)

Et... ça marche même pour une sphère... ;-)

Bon... formellement... cela ne vaut que si l'on exprime le volume en unités légales bien sûr.

Comment: @Fólkvangr : Je t'accorderai volontiers que l'on hésitera sans doute à écrire qu'un *cube cube un mêtre cube* ou qu'une *sphère cube un mêtre cube*... cela dit... demande à un amateur de gros mono *combien cube son **cylindre***, il comprendra tout de suite et te répondra même sans les unités, devenues implicite dans le verbe... :-) VaVaVOUM!

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! J'ai accepté la réponse de Greg car je ne peux en accepter qu'une mais la tienne paraît tout aussi satisfaisante.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que c'est important de mentionner que pour toutes les métriques qui n'ont pas de verbe spécifique, on utilise généralement *faire* (à l'oral en tout cas). On peut aussi l'utiliser dans les cas où il existe un verbe.

> Ce cube **fait** 1kg.
>
> Ce cube **fait** 50cm.
>
> Ce cube **fait** 1L.

Ce n'est pas la formulation la plus soutenue, mais elle fonctionne avec toutes les dimensions.

C'est particulièrement utilisé dans des contextes non-scientifiques où le mot précis pourrait être "trop technique". On ne dit pas "*Un marathon **mesure** 42km*" par exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Un volume est exprimé en [mètre cube](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A8tre_cube) dans le système international d'unités.

> Un cube d'un décimètre d'arête.

Vous confondez la définition géométrique d'un cube avec les propriétés physiques d'un cube particulier (son poids). Néanmoins, on dira « ce cube *fait* un décimètre cube » ou « ce cube fait un décimètre de côté » pour exprimer qu'on détermine le volume du cube ou, plus généralement, ses caractéristiques.

> Un cube mesurant un décimètre de côté. (les côtés sont tous égaux)
>   Un cube *d'un décimètre cube*. (complément du nom)